# How to create WordPress thickbox responsive that contains YouTube embed video?

Tags: wordpress, thickbox

I am trying to make a thickbox for youtube embed video. The current code is given below:

```
<?php add_thickbox(); ?>
<a id="cspd_yt_thickbox" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $yt_obj->videoId($i); ?>?TB_iframe=true" class="thickbox">
    <img style="display: inline; width: 250px;height: auto;" src="<?php echo $yt_obj->yt_thumb($i); ?>">
</a>
```

But both the thickbox and YouTube embed video is not responsive. please help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score -2):

As you are using Wordpress. So you have an option to install Thickbox Plugin for Wordpress. Below mentioned thickbox is responsive and dynamically fit the Images / Videos

https://wordpress.org/plugins/responsive-thickbox/

Comment: No, I don't need any other plugin. I am developing a plugin and it is the part of the plugin. I want to do it with the add_thickbox() function that is the part of core WordPress. I need to make it responsive. My plugin is a YouTube gallery plugin that uses the shortcode to add gallery in post and pages.

Comment: You can find add_thickbox() Function Examples Here. [link]https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/-/add_thickbox/php-add_thickbox-function-examples.html